# How can I behave when I will be ignored as a team member after my resignation?

Tags: software-industry, communication, resignation

I'm a software engineer and I worked in a startup for 11 months.Two months later I got a job offer and I resigned from my actual post and I'm still making the award period.

After the resignation of me and another member, the scrum master who works with us remotely made a meeting with others and increased their salaries in order to stay at the startup.

During the meeting or the evaluation, he thanks some of the team members for their achievements during the 11 months and their hard working without mentioning me. I passed many nights  working extras unpaid hours in company to fix the bugs of the application and analyzing some solutions to enhance some features in time where all the team members left work at 6pm and didn't add one minute even when there still some unreleased work and we have delivery tomorrow.

The scrum master meet us every day for 15 minutes by skype to know the state of the tasks and if there is a problem. He doesn't know what happens during the day in the office and who works hard or not. We have some kind of developers who love copy paste code from Google then they will be the heros of the team because they finished the work. There are a lot of problems and mistakes and bad behavior that happen every day but the scrum master didn't know about them. At the end the person who talks a lot will be the best developer in the team even if his work is not as well as desired.

Personally I found remote working of the scrum master is not fair and it doesn't give each person what he deserves. I think to discuss with him and clarify some points in order to not abuse another member in the future and gives him what he deserves even by a simple word of gratitude.

What is the suitable thing to do because I feel such I'm abused ?

Comment: Why do you care about the opinion of a scrum master in a company you are leaving? He is not your Boss or your reference, he has remote contact to you and probably is not a tech guy himself. The work you want to be acknowledged by is your code (my takeaway from the question). The tech leads or your direct boss are the people you should worry what opinion they have of you. But you are leaving the company, so what does it matter now?

Comment: Down playing or not mentioning your contributions is unprofessional, but you're already moving on the green pastures. I went through the same grieving process leaving a startup I gave 2 years of blood, sweat and tears to. My work on a number of major projects went completely unacknowledged too. It's important to remember why you are leaving and not get pulled back into the abusive work relationship.

Answer (score 17):

You've quit. You said to your employer: "I don't want to work for you any more, I've got a better job now". While your scrum master may not be the best, it's long past the time to pick a fight about it. Just work out your notice in a professional manner and move on - anything else makes you look like someone trying to score petty points while walking out the door.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Philip Kendall: You've resigned, there's no need to get involved and no need to do anything other than work out your notice period.

It is possible though that you would still like the company to succeed after you left, perhaps for the sake of friends who are still among the employees there, or because you believe in what they're doing for some reason. In this case it could be worth raising your concerns with your scrum master or even his management. Do so in an objective way, without sounding like (a) you are personally angry or pursuing a vendetta, or (b) intending to sue them for any reason. If you do so, your suggestions will actually carry a lot of weight because you will not have any personal motive, just be trying to help the company.

Honestly though, whether you feel sufficiently appreciated is completely irrelevant. You're leaving. They have no strong reason to show you appreciation at this point, and you have nothing to gain by pursuing the matter. You might get into a big long argument, with drawn-out meetings and complaints filed, all to finally end up with someone saying "thank you for all your hard work" while silently thinking something else. Is that worth it? You're leaving, so move on.